# How do we apply the custom functionality for the numpy nunique method?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, numpy, pandas-groupby

Let's consider the following code,

```
[sample.csv]
      Name   Year    Status
 1     ABC    2017    200
 2     DEF    2017    404
 3     GHI    2018    404
 4     JKL    2017    500
 5     MNO    2017    200
 6     PQR    2017    301
```

**Expected output,**

*Sum of no. of unique records count from 'status' column and grouping by the 'Year' column, **without** directly using **"nunique()"**, but with **"chunk"** concept (eg, 2 records at a time)*

As usual for getting the no. of unique values for the column,

```
dataset = pd.read_csv(source_file)
dataset.groupby(['year']).nunique()
```

Now I'm using the following code to achieve the "nunique()" functionality, but some times it's not returning the correct result while processing the very large CSV file (more than 5GB).

```
import pandas as pd

chunks = pd.read_csv(source_file, chunksize=100000)

data_grp1 = pd.DataFrame() 
for dataset in chunks:
    gb = dataset.groupby(['year'])
    #data_grp1 = gb['status'].nunique() 

    # If we apply the above method/line directly,
    # then our final result would not be correct (it is suitable for only 
    # one shot processing), so I'm using the following lines (Even, 
    # sometimes it is also returns the Incorrect result for large CSV files, 
    # small size files are OK!)

    data_grp1 = pd.concat([data_grp1, gb['status'].unique()])

def nu_fn(x):
    return len(set(np.concatenate(x.values, axis=0)))

res = data_grp1.groupby(['year'], level=0, axis=0)[0].apply(nu_fn)

print(res)
```

How do we achieve the same result without using the built in function "nunique()"?

Any idea, then please... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let's try something different, using `pd.factorize`:

```
df.groupby('Year')['Status'].apply(lambda x: max(pd.factorize(x)[0]) + 1)
```

Output:

```
Year
2017    4
2018    1
Name: Status, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Is it we have to use, instead `"res = data_grp1.groupby(['year'], level=0, axis=0)[0].apply(nu_fn)"`?

Answer (score 0):

You filtered on the chunk level but you did not filter across chunks:

```
data_grp1 = pd.concat([data_grp1, gb['status'].unique()])
```

What you need to do is to filter again after you constructed the final `data_grp1` like:

```
data_grp2 = data_grp1.groupby('Year').apply(lambda df: df.drop_duplicates(subset=['status']))
```

And then do your final analysis on `data_grp2`

Comment: I'm getting `KeyError: 'Year'`, If once I add the `"level=0"`, then I'm getting another issue, `KeyError: Index(['Status'], dtype='object')`